# Konsole crashes right after start

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde, crash, konsole

I have a problem with the application "Konsole" in Kubuntu 15.04. A few weeks ago everything worked fine, but then this problem occurred:
When I start Konsole it looks like this:

[image]

The app hangs completely and I have to kill the task to get rid of the window. I do not remember of any changes I made to the configuration of Konsole or the display manager. No other applications are affected.

At the moment I have to use xterm, which works fine, but is less comfortable for me.

I have already reinstalled konsole.

Comment: You can try using `xterm` to purge and reinstall `konsole`, but this is a little risky. Did you reboot?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yes of course I did a reboot... the problem occurred the first time a few weeks ago. But why is reinstalling konsole risky?

Comment: It's possible that it isn't installable through `apt-get`, but that's very unlikely.

Comment: I have the same problem! It launches fine, but then is unresponsive after rendering the first frame.

Comment: Yeah, new activity here :) No idea about any fix, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. After reading this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194875, I noted that I had a ~/.config/konsolerc.lock file. After removing it, konsole works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this solution but it sounds great.

Comment: Worked for me... thx